# Make a Video Match the size of its Parent Container (which uses vh and vw units)

Tags: html, css, video, alignment

I have a video element within a container, and I'd like it so that it fills the said parent container (the equivalent of background-size: cover; that is used for background images). The parent container of the video uses vw and vh units.

I'm really struggling.  I can get it so it fits the width just by using width: 100%, but height: auto doesn't fill the height of the container and using the same vw and vh measurements as the parent element is also unsuccessful.

How would i approach this - I seem to be go around in circles / pulling my hair out.

Is this going to need a JS solution?

Any ideas would be awesome. Code and Codepen link are below.

codepen: https://codepen.io/pauljohnknight/pen/EXwbzz

```js
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
video[0].play();
video[0].loop = true;
video[0].controls = false;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.videoholder {
  background: #666;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="videoholder">
    <video src="https://www.marketing-people.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/bakerbox-mockup.mp4" class="myvideo"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolute position the video tag to fill the parent container and then use `object-fit: cover;` on the video tag.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xgexdj

Update: This will not work in any version of IE. This is a polyfill that will get it working in IE 8 - 11. https://github.com/jonathantneal/fitie

Comment: thanks @wizardcoder that's great.  I saw as well that the next update for IE (Edge 16) which is being rolled imminently now has this property.  I'll add the polyfill though to cover myself  etc.

Answer (score 1):

like an image, if you use `width:100%` and `height:auto` , the video takes it's original dimensions and enlarges/decreases them so that it fits the whole width, but also keep the original aspect ratio

If you want the video to stretch on height, setting also `width:100%` will not work because it will try to keep the original aspect ratio

Similar to using `background-size:cover` ( that cuts away the image so it can fill the whole wrapper but also keep the ratio ) , you can use `width:auto` , `height:100%` , together with `overflow:hidden` on the wrapper

```js
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
video[0].play();
video[0].loop = true;
video[0].controls = false;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.videoholder {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 50vw;
 background:url("http://lorempixel.com/1140/450/") no-repeat scroll center top /cover  #666;
}

video {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="videoholder">
    <video src="https://www.marketing-people.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/bakerbox-mockup.mp4" class="myvideo"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai.  I did need a solution that used the video element, hence me marking the other answer as correct, but this is really useful to know as well.  Much appreciated.

Comment: well. except `overflow:hidden` . it does use video element